# How do I get a short URL for WeChat 公众号 posts?

Tags: url-shortening, wechat

I live in China and use WeChat to read 公众号 posts (kind of like a WeChat blog for companies, organizations, etc.).  Their raw URLs are often of formidable length, such as

> `https://mp.weixin.qq.com/s?__biz=MzI0NTYyMjg2NA==&mid=2247505130&idx=1&sn=2c7bf3923cb238c6df9ea8e88f3aa317&chksm=e94925d5de3eacc3f2bb6d762b8906d018eb362c9b76af7256d184045209aa2206b386370a68&mpshare=1&scene=1&srcid=0901x8X79E3WM9LxuhCCeY2y&sharer_sharetime=1662027321678&sharer_shareid=2a4f91494d8222139a5816a448f64faf&exportkey=AznpMuZiCnBXPIIgqxyR%2BVw%3D&acctmode=0&pass_ticket=O86F07s3jWcFGWht2xIbvGojygZ8V74Ad9WnMvlulfgR8s2NsUR3nVodf27PrhEj&wx_header=0#rd`

for [this link](https://mp.weixin.qq.com/s?__biz=MzI0NTYyMjg2NA==&mid=2247505130&idx=1&sn=2c7bf3923cb238c6df9ea8e88f3aa317&chksm=e94925d5de3eacc3f2bb6d762b8906d018eb362c9b76af7256d184045209aa2206b386370a68&mpshare=1&scene=1&srcid=0901x8X79E3WM9LxuhCCeY2y&sharer_sharetime=1662027321678&sharer_shareid=2a4f91494d8222139a5816a448f64faf&exportkey=AznpMuZiCnBXPIIgqxyR%2BVw%3D&acctmode=0&pass_ticket=O86F07s3jWcFGWht2xIbvGojygZ8V74Ad9WnMvlulfgR8s2NsUR3nVodf27PrhEj&wx_header=0#rd).  However, I've seen posts linked to using shorter URLs, such as:

> `https://mp.weixin.qq.com/s/VCGTJbG2Z_Hyq8WaD19Qag`

for [this link](https://mp.weixin.qq.com/s/VCGTJbG2Z_Hyq8WaD19Qag).

There's no obvious "share" button on these pages.  Googling [`How do I get a short URL for WeChat posts?`](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+do+I+get+a+short+URL+for+WeChat+posts%3F) doesn't give the answer for 公众号 posts.

**Question**: How do I get a short URL for WeChat 公众号 posts?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how I can do it on my iPhone.  Open the page in WeChat:

> [image: screenshot of opening the page in WeChat]

and click the ellipsis.  This pops up a menu, where you click the link icon (in blue I redact my WeChat friends' info):

> [image: screenshot of the link icon in WeChat]

This "copies" the short URL, and you can "paste" it elsewhere:

> [image: screenshot of the link copied prompt]

For this example, the short URL is `https://mp.weixin.qq.com/s/jba5bixw2Me09YHjqqEZUw` which links to [here](https://mp.weixin.qq.com/s/jba5bixw2Me09YHjqqEZUw).